# Binding doesn't work for the Textbox within a DataTemplate within a ContentPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

**My intention:** Display a message box with the text entered in "*userdata*" control on click of "*Show name*" button (with the help of data binding instead of directly accessing the "*userdata*" control's *Text* property). I wrote this code to understand the template concept in *WPF*.

**Issue with the below code:** *Databinding* doesn't happen as intended.

**NOTE**: However, if I remove the "*ContentPresenter*" and the "*DataTemplate*" surrounding the "*userdata*" control, data binding works fine. Any leads to make this code work will be helpful.

**Mainwindow.xaml:**

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="openFile">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid Width="300" Height="150">
                    <Rectangle Fill="Aquamarine" RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" />
                    <Ellipse Fill="Azure"></Ellipse>
                    <ContentPresenter>
                        <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="50">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Name" />
                                    <TextBox x:Name="userdata" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5" Width="100" />
                                    <Button Content="Show Name" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>            
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

**UserName.cs**

```
public class UserName : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            FirePropertyChange("Name");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void FirePropertyChange(string propertyName)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
UserName user = new UserName();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = user;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {           

        MessageBox.Show(user.Name);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataBinding doesn't happen as intended in ContentTemplate, because Content is not set. Add Content binding `<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}">`, and the rest will work

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}">
    <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="50">
                <TextBlock Text="Name" />
                <TextBox x:Name="userdata" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5" Width="100" />
                <Button Content="Show Name" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
</ContentPresenter>
```

Answer (score 1):

That happens because DataTemplate is a "wrapper" around button's content (Button.Content) and uses this content as own DataContext. When Content is not specified then DataContext of DataTemplate is null and binding fails.

To make code work properly you should specify Button.Content property (It should be an instance of UserName class).

You may use button's DataContext as button's content (this way is ugly as duck):

```
<Button Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DataContext}">
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Grid Width="300" Height="150">
            <ContentPresenter>
                <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="50">
                            <TextBlock Text="Name" />
                            <TextBox x:Name="userdata" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5" Width="100" />
                            <Button Content="Show Name"></Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
            </ContentPresenter>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

When you remove DataTemplate and ContentPresenter from the tree then TextBox just inherits parent's DataContext (instance of UserName) so binding works properly.

The best way is following MVVM pattern.

DataContext of a window:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public UserName User { get; } = new UserName();
}
```

Assign window data context:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
}
```

Bind button to user:

```
<Button Content="{Binding User}">
    <Button.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="50">
                <TextBlock Text="Name" />
                <TextBox x:Name="userdata" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5" Width="100" />
                <Button Content="Show Name"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Button.ContentTemplate>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid Width="300" Height="150">
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DataContext}` can be written simply as `{Binding}`

Comment: You are right, I used full form to make it clear what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved by changing the *userdata* control's XAML definition as below:

```
<TextBox x:Name="userdata" Text="{Binding DataContext.Name, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button,Mode=FindAncestor}}" Margin="5" Width="100" />
```

When there are nested templates, *compiler* may not be able to identify the correct parent. Hence it is necessary to mention the relative source with the ancestor type and the path with *DataContext.*bindingdata